# Corrupted argument stack in Android App with C++ Code

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I have some strange results in an Android App which uses native C++ Code via the Android NDK. When I make a call-by-value which a self-defined struct, somehow the values of the struct member get mixed up and corrupted. Here is the code which causes this:

Content of ndkfoo.h:

```
#ifndef NDKFOO_H_
#define NDKFOO_H_

typedef struct _Point
{
int x;
int y;
} Point;

typedef struct _TdTarget
{
Point tl;       /**< top-left corner */
Point tr;       /**< top-right corner */
Point br;       /**< bottom-right corner */
Point bl;       /**< bottom-left corner */
Point center; /**< estimated center point of the target */
} TdTarget;

#endif /* NDKFOO_H_ */
```

Content of ndkfoo.c:

```
#include "ndkfoo.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>

Point point(int x, int y){
    Point p;
    p.x = x;
    p.y = y;

    return p;
}

void doSomething(TdTarget trgt){
    int i = 0;
    int db1 = sizeof(TdTarget);
    int db2 = db1 + 5;
    if(i == 0)
        printf("");
}    

jstring Java_com_sbkr83_ndkfoo_NdkFooActivity_invokeNativeFunction(JNIEnv*          env,         jobject javaThis) {

TdTarget trgt;
trgt.tl = point(1,2);
trgt.tr = point(3,4);
trgt.br = point(5,6);
trgt.bl = point(7,8);
trgt.center = point(9,11);
int db4 = sizeof(TdTarget);
int db6 = db4 + 5;

doSomething(trgt);

  return "";
}
```

Content of Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# Here we give our module name and source file(s)
LOCAL_MODULE    := ndkfoo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ndkfoo.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Content of Application.mk:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
```

And content of NdkFooActivity:

```
package com.sbkr83.ndkfoo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class NdkFooActivity extends Activity {

  // load the library - name matches jni/Android.mk
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("ndkfoo");
  }

  // declare the native code function - must match ndkfoo.c
  private native String invokeNativeFunction();

  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // this is where we call the native code
        invokeNativeFunction();
    }
}
```

Here is the debugger output of the variables before and after doSomething has been called. Have a look at the values of the struct trgt:

Before calling:

```
env 0x0000aeb8  
javaThis    0x2afca558  
trgt    {...}   
    tl  {...}   
        x   1   
        y   2   
    tr  {...}   
        x   3   
        y   4   
    br  {...}   
        x   5   
        y   6   
    bl  {...}   
        x   7   
        y   8   
    center  {...}   
        x   9   
        y   11
```

And after calling doSomething:

```
trgt    {...}   
    tl  {...}   
        x   5   
        y   6   
    tr  {...}   
        x   7   
        y   8   
    br  {...}   
        x   9   
        y   11  
    bl  {...}   
        x   9   
        y   11  
    center  {...}   
i       2   
db1     1   
db2 2123359160
```

As you can see, the values got mixed up and corrupted. Very interesting is also, that the values of the local variables are not correct, too. It seems to me, that the stack frame with the local variables and arguments got totally messed. But I have no idea why. The same code runs without any mistakes on a windows Systems with MS Visual Studio.

My development system:
Windows XP SP 3 32-bit
Android SDK 19
Android NDK 7rb
Eclipse Indigo
Java JDK 7.3
Cygwin 1.7.11-1

The problem occurs also on other systems liek Win 7 or a Mac.

So, I would be very happy, if someone has an idea how to solve this and would be willing to share this ideas with me.

Thanks in advance!

Bye, Raoul.

Edit: It becomes clearer now. It seems, that the gdb debugger, we used to retrieve this values, just malfunctioned. We made some testlogs, via the Android log, in order to find out, if the debugger is working correctly.

So, the solution of tis question leads to the next question: Why does the ndk-gdb debugger not working correctly?

If someone has an idea for this, I would be quite thankful.

And I want to thanks a lot for the help we got.

Comment: Returning `""` from `jstring` method is just wrong. I would expect it to crash every time, actually. If you don't need return value, just use `void`. Also, where is code that prints values? How did you get those traces?